# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'last_name'

Tags: python, django

I've a problem with a form save. I've a model named `UserProfile`, like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

and a form to create an instance of the model, like this:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):  
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Introduzca su nombre', max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Introduzca sus apellidos', max_length=75)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Introduzca su email', max_length=50)
    birth_date = forms.DateField(label='Introduzca su fecha de nacimiento', widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Introduzca su contrasena', max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password_repeat = forms.CharField(label='Por favor, repita su contrasena', max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    ...
    def save(self):
        age = (date.today()-self.cleaned_data['birth_date']).days/365
        user = UserProfile(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                       last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                       email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                       password=self.cleaned_data['password'],
                       age=age)  # The error is detected in this line
        user.save()
        return user
```

It throws the following error line:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'last_name'
```

I don't know what's the problem, who can help me?

Comment: Is this Django? Are you sure `UserProfile` class is the same you've shown?

Comment: your constructor in UserProfile accept only one parameter (model,Model) not 5 ! that's why interpreter screaming about 'last_name'. Change the parameters you passing in UserProfile or create Model, and add this stuff like "first_name", "last_name" to model object, and pass this object to constructor.

Comment: @pkruk Where did you get this from? "[*The keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you’ve defined on your model.*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model)". The error does not seem to be in the code as shown.

Comment: Did you override `__init__`  method of the model class or the form class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

I think you have here `__init__` method which you didn't show. If you are using it should look like:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...  # your code here 
        super(UserProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...  # and/or here
```

In other words you've overridden `__init__` in way that its signature doesn't match the parent implementation's signature.

Comment: thank you warvariuc ;) I solved it, I removed all __init__ methods from all my models and it works